# Permission denied SSH key and bitbucket

Tags: ssh, bitbucket

In order to ensure security, I have added SSH public key to my Bitbucket account. This is working perfectly and no password is prompted since the private key is added to my machine using `ssh-add` command.

The problem I am facing now is it will not work after system restart. I have to use `ssh-add` command after every system restart. Can someone help me on this ?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the official documentation here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html ??

## Bitbucked instructions:

The steps for enabling ssh in bitbucket are the following:

In your workstation:

```
$ ssh-keygen
```

(you can omit the password here by pressing enter when asked if you wish to simply use the key-pair without entering a decryption password each time you login)

After this, verify the keys are generated:

```
$ ls -l ~/.ssh
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

Now you need to add the keys to your bitbucket settings:

- Go to the **Account settings**
- Click **ssh keys**
- Click **Add key**
- Write a "Label" with a descriptive sentence ("User Tismon at Home Workstation", for ex.).
- Copy the contents of `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the "Key" field (use `cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or open with a text editor, but make sure to copy everything from the file).
- Click **save**
- Verify everything is working as expected with `ssh -T git@bitbucked.org`

## Encrypted ssh keys:

There is no need to do `ssh-add` unless you set up a password for the keys. If you did, you have to make sure the `ssh-agent` is running and make sure you add the private key:

```
$ eval `ssh-agent` 
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you need an encrypted ssh-key, you have to ssh-add the key everytime you reboot, as ssh-add lasts as long as your session. If you don't want to enter the key or password everytime, the easiest way is not to encrypt it.

Comment: Exact these steps are followed as advised from bitbucket documentation and it works. But dont know how it failed after every system restart.

Comment: everytime whenever server restart either you have to load keys manually or add sometime to load automatically from rc.local or from profile to make it work after reboot.

Comment: @TismonVarghese Are you encrypting the key with a password? If you need an encrypted ssh-key, you have to ssh-add the key everytime you reboot, as ssh-add lasts as long as your session. If you don't want to enter the key or password everytime, the easiest way is not to encrypt it.